# Pass googlemaps polygon to MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

What I currently have is

```
function savePolygon(polygon) {
    var vertices = polygon.getPath();
    var fencePoints = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
        var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
        fencePoints.push({ lat: xy.lat(), lon: xy.lng() });
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Maps/Save",
        data: { polygon: fencePoints },
        beforeSend: function () {
            /* что-то сделать перед */
        },
        success: function (data) {
            /* обработать результат */
        },
        error: function () {
            /* обработать ошибку */
        }
    });

}
```

I am not really sure what my Controller `Save` method should accept as a parameter.

```
public string Save(string[] polygon)
{
    return null;
}
```

This way I receive an array with 5 null values

Is there a way to create a Polygon class or FencePoint class in such a way that it would be bound to parameter transferred via ajax?

Comment: Yes there is a way. Could you show your Javascript code? Of the polygon and/or FencePoints?

Comment: It is google-maps api object.